# When button is clicked, the database is updated

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I have this interface

[image]

When one of those buttons is clicked, it updates the database. For example I have a variable called "Estado" that, by default is "emAvaliacao", but when the button "Aceite" is pressed, the "Estado" changes to "Aceite".

Here are the functions that I use:

```
    function atualizaBD(idmarcador, novoEstado) {
    $.ajax
        ({
            url: `/api/IgnicoesAPI/${idmarcador}`,
            type: 'PUT',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                Id: +idmarcador,
                Estado: novoEstado
            }),
            success: function (result) {
                 connection.invoke("PostMarker").catch(function (err) {
                              return console.error(err.toString());
                 });
            },

            error: function () {
                alert("ocorreu um erro!")
            }
        });
}
```

Here is the PUT function:

```
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutIgnicoes([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Ignicoes ignicao)
    {
        
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }


        if (id != ignicao.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }


        var dataDecisao = DateTime.Now;
        var ig = _context.Ignicoes.FirstOrDefault (ignicaoId => ignicaoId.Id.Equals(id));
        if (ig != null)
        {
            ig.Estado = ignicao.Estado;              
            ig.DataDecisaoIgnicao = dataDecisao;
        }
        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!IgnicoesExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }
```

Right now it gives me an error 400, I have no idea why or how to fix this problem. Can someone help me?

Comment: Why is there a `+` in `Id: +idmarcador`?

Comment: Should `Id` be capitalized (should it be `id`)?  Javascript is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Debug to locate the specific line causing excepiton.

1. Is  `url` you post route to your action `PutIgnicoes`?

   From post code I can't see the right attribute route `[HttpPut("~/api/IgnicoesAPI/{id}")]`
2. Check parameters you post to action.

data: JSON.stringify({ Id: +idmarcador, Estado: novoEstado   }),

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PutIgnicoes([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Ignicoes ignicao)
```

Answer (score 0):

Error 400 is mainly caused by the `return BadRequest();` in your action. You should debug to see payload and check if the data can be bind to the Ignicoes model.

If there still some problem. Please show use the `Ignicoes` class and the request payload.